# Why do bonds with positive and negative charges not collapse?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, strong-force, chemical-compounds

I previously believed that the reason positive and negative charges don't constantly attract until they collapse is due to a repulsive strong force at small distances. However, in a textbook by Tipler, he claims that there is an electron degeneracy pressure (at small distances, electron wave functions overlap, forcing other electrons to attain higher energy states due to Pauli's exclusion principle). He argues that this increases the potential energy at small distances. So which is it? Electron degeneracy pressure or the strong force? Are they somehow connected?

Comment: how would a second attractive force prevent opposite charges from collapsing together?

Comment: Sorry I meant repuslive

Answer (score 1):

> I previously believed that the reason positive and negative charges don't constantly attract until they collapse is due to an repulsive strong force at small distances.

This is wrong. The reason that quantum mechanics was discovered/invented *was* due to the fact the atoms existed, electrons and protons made hydrogen atoms with specific spectra, and hydrogen was stable. Positive to negative attraction has a limit. [The Bohr model](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/bohr.html) imposing quantized orbits started the story that became quantum mechanics with the Schrodinger equation solution for the hydrogen atom. There is always the lowest energy level for the electron to occupy.

So, atoms and molecules are neutral and have electrons in orbitals about the nucleus, the orbitals are solutions of the quantum mechanical equations for the specific atoms.

Here is how,because of the geometric shape of the [orbitals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital), positive and negative regions appear between atoms and molecules:

[image: orbitals]

> The five d orbitals in ψ(x, y, z)2 form, with a combination diagram showing how they fit together to fill space around an atomic nucleus.

These create LEGO like attractive and repulsive regions when two such atoms are next to each other, and bonds can form.

> > However, in a textbook by Tipler, he claims that there is an electron degeneracy pressure (at small distances, electron wave functions overlap, forcing other electrons to attain higher energy states due to Pauli's exclusion principle

This is a higher order effect, as far as a "collapse of negative on positive" goes. The proximity of the electron orbitals from different atoms, due to the Pauli exclusion principle affects the combined orbitals of molecules.

The strong force is the force keeping the quarks bound within the proton and the neutron and plays no role in atomic and molecular bonds. ( except possibly in some nuclear interactions specific to unstable nuclei, as [electron capture)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_capture).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say electron degeneracy is a higher order effect, and if this isn't the correct force, then what is?

Comment: as I said, quantization is what keeps the charges apart. Higher order because the degeneracy is a correction of the basic energy level of the solution of the quantum mechanical problem